# Distinct sub sequences summing to given number in an array

Tags: algorithm

During my current preparation for interview, I encountered a question for which I am having some difficulty to get optimal solution,
We are given an array `A` and an integer `Sum`, we need to find all distinct sub sequences of `A` whose sum equals `Sum`.
For eg. `A={1,2,3,5,6}` `Sum=6` then answer should be
`{1,2,3}`
`{1,5}`
`{6}`

Presently I can think of two ways of doing this,

1. Use Recursion ( which I suppose should be last thing to consider for an interview question)
2. Use Integer Partitioning to partition `Sum` and check whether the elements of partition are present in `A`

Please guide my thoughts.

Comment: What is your *specific* question here?

Comment: is the array always sorted?

Comment: my question is what is the optimal solution to the said problem

Comment: "*( which I suppose should be last thing to consider for an interview question)*" What makes you think that?

Comment: @gkovacs90 No it can be in any form

Comment: I would use backtrack here

Comment: @Jason I heard this from peoples who already faced interview before. This is my first time

Comment: @Bond: That sounds ridiculous to me; recursion is a perfectly acceptable way to solve problems.

Comment: @all means its `ok` if I go with recursion ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fast solution to Subset sum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809436/fast-solution-to-subset-sum)

Comment: @Tyler Durden: Disagree. It is the *same* problem, but not in the context of an interview.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Jason. This solution comes to mind:
(complexity is `O(sum*|A|)` if you represent the map as an array)

- Call the input set A and the target sum `sum`
- Have a map of elements B, with each element being `x:y`, where `x` (the map key) is the sum and `y` (the map value) is the number of ways to get to it.
- Starting of, add `0:1` to the map - there is 1 way to get to 0 (obviously by using no elements)
- For each element `a` in A, consider each element `x:y` in B.

  - If `x+a` > `sum`, don't do anything.
  - If an element with the key `x+a` already exists in B, say that element is `x+a:z`, modify it to `x+a:y+z`.
  - If an element with the key doesn't exist, simply add `x+a:y` to the set.
- Look up the element with key `sum`, thus `sum:x` - `x` is our desired value.

If B is sorted (or an array), you can simply skip the rest of the elements in B during the "don't do anything" step.

**Tracing it back:**

The above just gives the count, this will modify it to give the actual subsequences.

At each element in B, instead of the sum, store all the source elements and the elements used to get there (so have a list of pairs at each element in B).

For `0:1` there is no source elements.

For `x+a:y`, the source element is `x` and the element to get there is `a`.

During the above process, if an element with the key already exists, enqueue the pair `x/a` to the element `x+a` (enqueue is an `O(1)` operation).

If an element with the key doesn't exist, simply create a list with one pair `x/a` at the element `x+a`.

To reconstruct, simply start at `sum` and recursively trace your way back.

We have to be careful of duplicate sequences (do we?) and sequences with duplicate elements here.

**Example - not tracing it back:**

A=`{1,2,3,5,6}`
sum = `6`

B = `0:1`

Consider `1`
Add `0+1`
B = `0:1, 1:1`

Consider `2`
Add `0+2:1`, `1+2:1`
B = `0:1, 1:1, 2:1, 3:1`

Consider `3`
Add `0+3:1` (already exists -> add `1` to it), `1+3:1`, `2+1:1`, `3+1:1`
B = `0:1, 1:1, 2:1, 3:2, 4:1, 5:1, 6:1`

Consider `5`
B = `0:1, 1:1, 2:1, 3:2, 4:1, 5:2, 6:2`
Generated sums thrown away = `7:1, 8:2, 9:1, 10:1, 11:1`

Consider `6`
B = `0:1, 1:1, 2:1, 3:2, 4:1, 5:2, 6:3`
Generated sums thrown away = `7:1, 8:1, 9:2, 10:1, 11:2, 12:2`

Then, from `6:3`, we know we have 3 ways to get to 6.

**Example - tracing it back:**

A=`{1,2,3,5,6}`
sum = `6`

B = `0:{}`

Consider `1`
B = `0:{}, 1:{0/1}`

Consider `2`
B = `0:{}, 1:{0/1}, 2:{0/2}, 3:{1/2}`

Consider `3`
B = `0:{}, 1:{0/1}, 2:{0/2}, 3:{1/2,0/3}, 4:{1/3}, 5:{2/3}, 6:{3/3}`

Consider `5`
B = `0:{}, 1:{0/1}, 2:{0/2}, 3:{1/2,0/3}, 4:{1/3}, 5:{2/3,0/5}, 6:{3/3,1/5}`
Generated sums thrown away = `7, 8, 9, 10, 11`

Consider `6`
B = `0:{}, 1:{0/1}, 2:{0/2}, 3:{1/2,0/3}, 4:{1/3}, 5:{2/3,0/5}, 6:{3/3,1/5,0/6}`
Generated sums thrown away = `7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12`

Then, tracing back from `6`: (not in `{}` means an actual element, in `{}` means a map entry)

```
{6}
  {3}+3
    {1}+2+3
      {0}+1+2+3
      1+2+3
      Output {1,2,3}
    {0}+3+3
      3+3
      Invalid - 3 is duplicate
  {1}+5
    {0}+1+5
      1+5
      Output {1,5}
  {0}+6
    6
      Output {6}
```

Comment: thanks for nice explanation. I have not made code for it, but it seems it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variant of the subset-sum problem. The subset-sum problem asks *if* there is a subset that sums to given a value. You are asking for *all* of the subsets that sum to a given value.

The subset-sum problem is hard (more precisely, it's [NP-Complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857244/np-vs-np-complete-vs-np-hard-what-does-it-all-mean/1857342#1857342)) which means that your variant is hard too (it's not NP-Complete, because it's not a decision problem, but it is NP-Hard).

The classic approach to the subset-sum problem is either recursion or dynamic programming. It's obvious how to modify the recursive solution to the subset-sum problem to answer your variant. I suggest that you also take a look at the [dynamic programming solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution) to subset-sum and see if you can modify it for your variant (tbc: I do not know if this is actually possible). That would certainly be a very valuable learning exercise whether or not is possible as it would certainly enhance your understanding of dynamic programming either way.

It would surprise me though, if the *expected* answer to your question is anything but the recursive solution. It's easy to come up with, and an acceptable approach to the problem. Asking for the dynamic programming solution on-the-fly is a bit much to ask.

You did, however, neglect to mention a very naïve approach to this problem: generate all subsets, and for each subset check if it sums to the given value or not. Obviously that's exponential, but it does solve the problem.

Comment: I tried dynamic programming before but till now I am only able to count number of sub sequences but unable to trace the sequence back. Is it possible to trace the sequence through it ?

Comment: To be completely honest, I don't know but I don't think so. Sorry if that wasn't clear, but that's why I merely said "see" if you can modify it.

Comment: This is not a "variant" of the subset sum problem, it *is* the subset sum problem. The wikipedia lists various algorithms.

Comment: No *the* subset-sum problem is a decision problem, it asks *if* there is a subset, not for all of the subsets. These are different problems, but obviously extremely closely related.

Comment: "Obviously that's exponential" - All solutions that generate a complete solution to this problem will be exponential, unless P = NP, so there's really no reason not to use brute force, unless you are looking for a fast way to get an approximate solution, or more restrictions are put on the input.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that given array contains distinct numbers.
Let's define function f(i, s) - which means we used some numbers in range [1, i] and the sum of used numbers is s.

Let's store all values in 2 dimensional matrix i.e. in cell (i, j) we will have value for f(i, j). Now if have already calculated values for cells which are located upper or lefter the cell (i, s) we can calculate value for f(i, s) i.e. f(i, s) = f(i - 1, s);(not to take i indexed number) and if(s >= a[i]) f(i, s) += f(i - 1, s - a[i]). And we can use bottom-up approach to fill all the matrix, setting [f(0, 0) = 1; f(0, i) = 0; 1 <= i <= s], [f(i, 0) = 1;1<=i<=n;]. If we calculated all the matrix then we have answer in cell f(n,S); Thus we have total time complexity O(n*s) and memory complexity O(n*s);

We can improve memory complexity if we note that in every iteration we need only information from previous row, it means that we can store matrix of size 2xS not nxS. We reduced memory complexity up to linear to S. This problem is NP complete thus we don't have polynomial algorithm for this and this approach is the best thing.