# Calculating if sum of subsets of a given list exists recursively

Tags: python-2.7, recursion

I need to build a recursive function that receives an integer list (numbers) and a non-negative integer (target).

The function will look for any possible subset of the given list and if its values are added up and equal to the target, returns `True`.

```
def subset_sum(numbers, target):
    '''
    numbers - a list of positive integers
    target - a non-negative integer
    returns True if the list 'numbers' has a sub-list with sum 'target',
            False otherwise.
    '''

Side Note: [] is a subset of any given list (set)
```

Examples:

```
subset_sum([1,2,3,4], 8):

True

subset_sum([1,2,3,4], 11):

False

subset_sum([4,4,4], 05):

True

subset_sum([4,4,4], 11):

False

subset_sum([], 0):

True
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: And the problem is ...?

Comment: That i had failed to do so, and currently looking for help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variant (sub-problem) on the subset sum problem which you can read about here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

There is a pseudocode algorithm outlined that solves the problem approximately in polynomial time for any integers (positive or negative). Interestingly enough this is posted on Stackoverflow and in python!

[Fast solution to Subset sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809436/fast-solution-to-subset-sum)