# Finding Deci-Binary for given input

Tags: java

Can anybody have solution for finding Deci-Binary ( Decimal numbers contains 0 and 1 like 100 111 101 ,.etc and numbers like 12, 13 and 5551 are not Deci-Binary)

**Numbers used here are decimal only nothing is in Binary format.**

Output is not in Binary format. Sum of all numbers in output should be same as Input.  For example below Input is Decimal 4 and output is decimals 1,1,1 and 1. When adding all the output we can get the input.

If input is 11 then, that is a deci-binary so we don't want to convert it. so the output will be same as input 11.

For input 4 
Output should be 1 1 1 1

Other scenarios as below

```
IP: 4
OP: 1 1 1 1

IP: 21
OP: 10 11 

IP: 11
OP: 11

IP: 100 
OP: 100 

IP: 99
OP: 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11
```

I tried, could not resolve it.

EDIT: This is not duplicate of [Finding shortest combinations in array/sequence that equals sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964289/finding-shortest-combinations-in-array-sequence-that-equals-sum) my question is not a sub-set problem and completly different form that question

Comment: What's the logic here? And can you share what you've tried?

Comment: Please share the your code snippet.

Comment: Why is `99` -> `11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11`? please explain

Comment: You can check this link : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-program-for-decimal-to-binary-conversion/

Comment: It seems there are various different definitions of "decibinary". What's yours?

Comment: If your intention is to convert decimal inputs into binary outputs then your test data is flawed i.e. the number ```4``` is ```100``` in decimal. Thus please clarify your question or check your test data.

Comment: @ernest_k, Lino, and Bewu   please refer updated question.

Comment: For clarification: The input needs to be be divided in groups of decimals that only consist of 1 and 0, is that assumption right? How should multiple possible solutions be handled? I.e. the input ```97``` would be valid as ```11 11 11 11 11 11 11 10 10``` and ```11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1``` and many more different combinations of 1, 10 and 11. Also consider adding a definition of deci-binaries as you need it (as suggested by Klitos) because that term is ambiguous.

Comment: @BeWu Yes correct. The answer should be minimum split count. First one in your example is correct. I came to know this term in an interview. So I wrote it as I heard. Sorry if anything wrong.

Comment: Considering minimum split count, the problem can be reduced to Min-Coin_Change-Problem ("https://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Min-Coin_Change").
see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964289/finding-shortest-combinations-in-array-sequence-that-equals-sum
With "coins" [1,10,11,100,101,110,111,1000,1001,1010,1011,1100,...]"
The approach requires to build the "coin"-list up to value and feed it into the algorithm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding shortest combinations in array/sequence that equals sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964289/finding-shortest-combinations-in-array-sequence-that-equals-sum)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution with slightly different approach

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printDeciBin(1);
    printDeciBin(4);
    printDeciBin(10);
    printDeciBin(11);
    printDeciBin(19);
    printDeciBin(21);
    printDeciBin(99);
    printDeciBin(100);
}

public static void printDeciBin(int number) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%d -> %s", number, findDeciBins(number).stream()
            .map(Object::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" "))));
}

static Collection<Integer> findDeciBins(int number) {
    List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
    while (number != 0) {
        l.add(number % 10);
        number /= 10;
    }
    Collections.reverse(l);


    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    while (true) {
        boolean stop = true;
        int curr = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
            curr *= 10;
            if (l.get(i) != 0) {
                curr++;
                l.set(i, l.get(i) - 1);
                stop = false;
            }
        }
        if (stop){
            break;
        }
        result.add(curr);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems the logic here is a bunch of written binaray numbers (consisting of 1 or 0) are added as decimal numbers until the sum results in the requested number.

So all you have to do is to find the maximum possible "*deci-binary*" and do
this as long as you have your sum.

To print or to find the maximum decbinary, you will need the "length" of the current decibinary, `log10` will help.

Java-Code:

```
package de.test.lang.stackexchange;

import java.util.Collection;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

public class DeciBins {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printDeciBin(1);
        printDeciBin(4);
        printDeciBin(10);
        printDeciBin(11);
        printDeciBin(19);
        printDeciBin(21);
        printDeciBin(99);
        printDeciBin(100);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("UseOfSystemOutOrSystemErr")
    public static void printDeciBin(int number) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%d -> %s", number, StringUtils.join(findDeciBins(number), " ")));
    }

    // finds the array of deciBins by determining the maximum possible
    // deciBin and subtract it, until 0.
    static Collection<Integer> findDeciBins(int number) {
        Collection<Integer> decis = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
        int deciBin = number;
        while (deciBin > 0) {
            int y = find_maximum_decibinary(deciBin); // (e.g. for 99 => 11)
            deciBin -= y;
            decis.add(y);
        }
        return decis;
    }

    // finds the maximum decibin by determining the max length and substract 1
    // until the val is smaller or equal the requested value x.
    static int find_maximum_decibinary(int x) {
        int l = (int) Math.ceil(Math.log10(x + 1));
        int currMax = (1 << l) - 1;
        while (currMax > 0) {
            int curVal = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toBinaryString(currMax));
            if (curVal <= x) {
                return curVal;
            }
            currMax--;
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `21` -> `10 11`? Shouldn't it be `11 10` then?

Comment: Valid argument. Dunno, maybe one can sort the array of decibinaries afterwards.

Comment: Or probably just reverse the list. Anyway it is not correct answer until author explains what he want to achieve.

Comment: @talex order is not a matter. Out put is fine.