# Algorithm for selecting k element out of n element array whose sum is zero

Tags: java, c++, algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Subset sum Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012963/subset-sum-problem)

I have an array of n elements. Find out k elements out of n whose corresponding sum is zero??

Suppose there is array of 5 elements{ 7, 5 ,-2,8 ,-5}and k=3 then the solution is 7,-2,-5.
the array and k is user defined

There is recursive solution of running time O(2^k)i.e kth power of 2.

Can anyone recommend the better solution??

Comment: So you want a set of elements out of your array that sum to 0? What does your solution look like now?

Comment: Is K fixed, or can you choose your value?