# Find thresholds of bins by sum of column values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, split

I need to find thresholds of bins (for ex. 0-999, 1000-1999 etc.), so that on each bin there was approximately an equal amount (1/n of total value, for ex 1/3 if we split into 3 bins).

```
d = {'amount': [600,400,250,340,200,500,710]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

amount
600
400
250
340
200
500
710
```

expected output if we split into 3 bins by sum of amount column:

```
bin                          sum
threshold_1(x value-x value) 1000
threshold_2(x-x)             1000
threshold_3(x-x)             1000
```

something like this, but i need sum value instead of count

```
pd.cut(amount, 3).value_counts()
```

maybe it could be solved in python, not only via pandas?

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. You want to create equal sized bins from the sum of all your values, than you have your answer: sum up all your values and divided by the number of bins, than you have the size of your bins.

Comment: @Bastian edited, the question is to find threshold values of equal bins

Answer (score 1):

If need approximately an equal amount aggregate `sum` with `pd.cut`:

```
df = df.groupby(pd.cut(df.amount, 3)).sum()
print (df)
                 amount
amount                 
(199.49, 370.0]     790
(370.0, 540.0]      900
(540.0, 710.0]     1310
```

Comment: almost looks what i nedd, but is it possible to split more equal amouts? because  on main df i've got not so good result: 1455511239 in first bin vs 29959759 in last

Comment: @Kurasao - I think not in my opinion, if need use some pandas methods.

Comment: @Kurasao - in python it is possible, but not so easy - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42271009/subsets-having-same-sum-python)