# Pandas binning column by equal sum of other column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have data frame like this

[image]

I need to bin 'a' column into n intervals (5 for example), but intervals must have equal or similar sum of 'b' value

I want result similar to pd.cut on 'a' column

[image]

But if we group by sum must be equal or similar (not as on next pic, made with pd.cut)
[image]

Comment: I updated what I want as a result

Comment: That's a pretty complex situation. I'd say, for this particular example, `df.groupby(pd.cut(df.a, [0,1,3,5,8,10])).b.sum()` would get you fairly close (i.e. `[20, 30, 30, 30, 30]`), but I'm just doing that manually. Not sure what the calculation for that answer would look like, maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42271733/18470692) could help in steering you in the right direction.