# Get indices of elements in a list that satisfies certain sum value

Tags: python, list, conditional-statements, selection

I tried to get the indices of elements in a list, which summed of the value equal to certain number.

```
a = [50, 50, 50, 50, 75, 75]
b = 125
```

in the example above, I am looking for indices of element in list a that summed values equal to b (=125). indices combination that I am looking for is [0, 4], corresponding to the first number 50 and the first number 75.

I found a way by first creating possible combinations of the element in list a using itertools.combinations and then filter all combination that summed value equal to 125. it leads to indices [0,4], [1,4], [2,4],... This is quite problematic for list a that has many elements.

is there any simple way in python?

thank you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: Looking at this in hindsight, this seems to be a derivative of the subset-sum problem, which is NP-complete.  There is no efficient algorithm to find what you're looking for save iterating through all possible combinations.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012963/subset-sum-problem

Comment: thanks for the reply..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 li = []
 for i,j in enumerate(a):
      for z,x in enumerate(a):
         if int(x)+int(j) == int(b) and i>z:
             li.append([i,z])
```

Comment: That only handles pairs of indices. What about triples? Quadruples? It's not just limited to pairs.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [50, 50, 50, 50, 75, 75]
b = 125
lst = []
def temp(a,b):
    for i in range(0,len(a)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(a)):
            if((a[i]+a[j]==b)&(len(lst)==0)):
                print(i,j)
                lst.append(i)
                lst.append(j)
temp(a,b)
print(lst)
```

The above code creates a populated array called `a`, and an empty one called `lst`, along with a variable called `b`.

The function `temp`, which takes two parameters of `a` and `b` loops through the list `a` and then loops through the list `a` again with a positive offset of one while checking if the current and the next number added together equal `b`.

If the two numbers added together equal `b` and the list `lst` is empty, the code prints the `index` of the two numbers, and adds the index of the two numbers to the list `lst`

Finally the list `lst` is printed.